# How do you access the user library on a time machine backup

Tags: macos, time-machine

With Lion 10.7, how does one access the user library on a time machine backup through the Finder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the Finder. In the menu bar, select Go, then hold down <kbd>Option</kbd>. Select the "Library" option which appears.

Then enter Time Machine as per normal.

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing your Time Machine Backup with "Browse Other Backup Disks...", like you do if you created a fresh install of your OS, the solution from dan8394 does not work.

Probably because Time Machine can't know that your current Library folder is a newer version of the Library folder in the backup.

However, the solution proposed in a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39026/how-do-i-access-the-user-library-from-a-time-machine-backup) that was closed as exact duplicate of this one works.

Lri helped me a lot with this answer:

> The Library folder is probably just hidden by Finder. You can show ***all
> hidden files*** by running this in Terminal:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true && osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'
> ```
>
> *(**Note**: The part after the `&&` will cause finder to stop, and you may need to restart it. So be aware that any open Finder windows may disappear.)*
>
> Changing `true` to `false` reverts the setting.

Comment: Thank-you! This is exactly what I needed, and what the Apple Genius wouldn't tell me.