# How do I access the user Library from a Time Machine backup?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you access the user library on a time machine backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21295/how-do-you-access-the-user-library-on-a-time-machine-backup)

I need to access my library folder in a time machine backup that is from a different mac.

How can I do this?

The real problem is that I backed up with time machine, reinstalled the OS and when I tried to put everything back I ran into problems. I tried using migration assistant, and it transferred everything but my user (which is basically just applications). I was able to right click on the time machine icon and browse what is in the backup file - thus manually restoring all of my data, however, without having access to the library folder there are many things I am unable to copy over.

Comment: related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21295/how-do-you-access-the-user-library-on-a-time-machine-backup

Answer (score 2):

The Library folder is probably just hidden by Finder. You can show hidden files by running this in Terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true && osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'`

Changing `true` to `false` reverts the setting.